# Spring-retry restarts after maxAttempts reached when no recover method is provided

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

Playing with spring-retry with spring-boot 1.5.21 and noticing that spring-retry restarts when maxAttempts is reached when there is no recover method implemented.

Works as expected if proper recover method is implemented. If no recover method, retry doesnt stop at maxAttempts, but restarts again. # of restarts is equal to configured maxAttempts. Eg, max attempts =3, retry will execute 9 times (running 3 retries * 3 restarts)

Using annotations to setup the retry block
@Retryable(include= {ResourceAccessException.class}, maxAttemptsExpression = "${retry.maxAttempts}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression  = "${retry.delay}", multiplierExpression = "${retry.delay-multiplier}"))

expected results with a maxAttempts =3 is retry stops after 3 attempts
actual results is retry will restart the 3 attempts 3 more times, for a total of 9 retries.

The above occurs ONLY when no recover method is provided. Based on documentation, recover method is optional and i have no need for one, since there is no valid recovery in my case for a failed REST service call. (no redundant service available)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no recoverer, the final exception is thrown.

If the source of the call is a listener container (e.g. RabbitMQ, JMS) then the delivery will be retried.

That's the whole point of a recoverer.